# What's the name of this citation style?

Tags: citations, paper-submission, citation-style, reference-managers

I am working on a research paper, and the journal I am submitting to requires a specific citation style for references. However, I am having trouble finding the correct format for one of my references on Zotero.

Here are the references:

> [1] Buzdugan, Gh., Izolarea antivibratorie, Ed. Academiei Romane,
> Bucuresti, 1993.
>
> [2] Le Roux, J.P., Comparation of sphericity indices as related to the
> hydraulic equivalence of setting grains, Journal of Sedimentary
> Research, vol. 67, no. 3, 1997, p. 527 – 530.
>
> [3] Murariu, G., Dariescu, C., Dariescu, M. A., Interacting fields - a
> complet analytical solution, Proceedings of the VI-th International
> Conference “ComTi” Timisoara, Romania, 2003, p. 238-239.
>
> [4] Smith, J., U.S. Patent 8,143,241, 1998.
>
> [5] http://pubs.ub.ro/?pg=revues&rev=mocm&sc=instructions
> (25.07.2010).
>
> [6] Stanchev Т., Systema za expresno opredeliane sprotivlenieto na
> toplopreminvane na ograjdenia v jibotnovdny sgrady, Selskostopanskaya
> Nauka, vol.5, 2008, p. 9-15.

I have tried searching for this citation style on Zotero, but I have not been able to find it. Can someone please help me identify the correct format for this citation?

Comment: Despite the trouble you have gone to, there is still not enough information to determine the citation style. The reason is that citation style refers to the *combination* of both the way the inline citation is done, which might be, for example as "[1]" or as "Buzdugan (1993)" **and** how the bibliography is formatted. I suggest that in your question you do two extra things. First, give an example sentence showing how the inline citation appears. Second, tell us what journal it is!!!!

Comment: @CrimsonDark this is the Journal of Engineering Studies and Research (JESR), the inline citation is done as following [1]

Comment: It's somewhat like the IEEE style. You can see an example in MS Word, which is the only place I know to see it.

Answer (score 2):

I used the link on [this page on Zotero support](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/citation_styles/style_editing_step-by-step) to go to [this page on citation styles](https://editor.citationstyles.org/about/) where I used the search by example feature, where I was ***unable to find*** any style that matched exactly. (To use the citation style matcher, it doesn't actually matter whether you are using Zotero, Endnote, or something else)

In circumstances where there is no suitable matching style for whatever citation-management-software (CMS) you are using, you have three different options:

1. Abandon the use of CMS altogether and do your inline citations and referencing manually. This is an extreme choice and I don't recommend it.
2. Use the closest CMS style that you can find (in your case, ***IEEE numbered*** seems to be an approximation) and then edit the references manually once your paper is complete. This method can work well ... but it pays to wait until the very late stages of preparing your paper. I have submitted papers to some journals where I knew that the referencing I had did not quite fit their style ... but I also knew that it wouldn't affect the review process and I could fix the style just before publication if my paper was accepted.
3. Take the time to use your CMS to edit an existing style so as to fit the style of the new journal. The value of doing this for you, personally, will depend on how much you enjoy hacking (!), and how often you're likely to submit to the particular journal. Others can also benefit from your work if you give your newly created style file to the citation software producer. I know that Zotero has a community upload site but I don't know about other citation managers.

I should say that one of the difficulties you will encounter in producing suitable formatting for the Journal of Engineering Studies and Research (JESR) is that there are only four (!) examples of formatted references in their [author-guidelines](https://I%20do%20not%20know%20the%20name%20of%20the%20style.%20Perhaps%20more%20importantly,%20%201.%20I%20used%20the%20link%20on%20%5Bthis%20page%20on%20Zotero%20support%5D%5B1%5D%20to%20go%20to%20%5Bthis%20page%20on%20citation%20styles%5D%5B2%5D%20where%20I%20used%20the%20search%20by%20example%20feature,%20where%20I%20was%20***unable%20to%20find***%20any%20style%20that%20matched%20exactly.%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/citation_styles/style_editing_step-by-step%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://editor.citationstyles.org/about/); in contrast, the
American Psychological Society has dozens.  Fortunately, the JESR does give "default advice" on in the author-guidelines:

> For other types of publications, where there is doubt include all bibliographical details.
> Web references: As a minimum, the full URL should be given. It is indicated to include the date when the reference was last accessed.